# Суффиксы прилагательных, образованных от существительных иностранного происхождения

Tags: словообразование

В прилагательных, которые образуются от существительных иностранного происхождения используются заимствованные суффиксы. Например, артерия-артериАЛЬный, но вена-венОЗный. Однако это наблюдается не всегда, в некоторых случаях используется классический суффикс -н-, например, лизосома-лизосомный. Существует ли какое-то правило, которое объясняет такое словообразование? (В частности при написании научной статьи о клеточной структуре "протеасома", я использовал прилагательное протеасомальный, но редактор журнала утверждает, что надо писать протеасомный. Я-то согласен, но тогда надо писать артерийный, бактерийный и т.д.).
Имя существительное в русском языке: протеасома (на английском - proteasome)
Имя прилагательное в английском: proteasomal. Протеасома (от англ. protease — протеиназа и лат. soma — тело) - крупная внутриклеточная структура, осуществляющая расщепление белков.

Answer (score 2):

Прежде всего, вам не стоит выдумывать какие-то правила или аналогии. Это самодеятельность, в научном стиле не приветствуемая.

Такие вещи не регулируются и не могут регулироваться каким-то исчерпывающим сводом правил. Иногда в литературе закрепляются термины просто потому что первый переводчик употребил именно такую форму. В любом случае надо убедиться, что именно ваш вариант фиксируется словарями, хотя бы специальными. Если в словарях нет, то посмотрите, используется ли вообще термин где-либо, при расхождении вариантов, пользуйтесь тем, который кажется более авторитетным. Если уж и в литературе нет, то по возможности избегайте таких неологизмов.

Конкретно по вашему вопросу.

> редактор журнала утверждает, что надо писать протеасомный

У меня под рукой нет ни медицинского словаря, ни даже биологического. 
"Асомальный" гугл находит в одном документе, асомный - почаще, но в каких-то совсем неподобающих значениях.

Установить значение английского Asomal мне не удалось. Вам вообще бы такие вещи в тексте вопроса раскрвать, а то гадать приходится на кофейной гуще.

Тут вот какая штука. Если Asomal в языке-источнике существительное, то прилагательное к нему естественно будет "асомальный". Если же asomal - само по себе прилагательное, то тащить иностранный суффикс в переводной термин нет никакого смысла. Это лишь некоторые мысли по поводу, как сказал, критерием служить не может, но иногда подобными рассуждениями руководствуются переводчики, тем самым закрепляя традицию.

> Я-то согласен, но тогда надо писать артерийный, бактерийный и т.д.).

Нет. Все аналогии, как уже сказал, совершенно не авторитетный источник. Тем более, что отдельные словоформы (типа бактерийный = воспроизводимый с помощью бактерий) могут быть "заняты" другим значением.

(+)

> Имя существительное... (на английском -
>   proteasome) Имя прилагательное в английском: proteasomal.

Если это единственные значения и существительное с прилагательным не путается, то русское прилагательное на мой вкус - ***протеасомный***.

Comment: Полное название структуры - протеасома (proteasome). В англоязычных статьях есть прилагательное proteasomal. Таким образом, я с Вами согласен, тащить суффикс ал нет смысла, это не часть существительного. Редактор прав. Хотя есть русскоязычные весьма авторитетные статьи, которые используют форму протеасомальный, но насколько я могу судить - это не устоявшееся слово. Раз не существует четких правил для таких слов, тогда действительно надо использовать устоявшиеся формы и не "изобретать" особенно в научно тексте. Спасибо.

Comment: *Полное название структуры - протеасома (proteasome).* - это-то я могу догадаться. ***Значение дайте и пример употребления***. А согласны вы со мной или нет - это вопрос совершенно не существенный.

Comment: Я добавил происхождение и значение слова в вопрос, как Вы и рекомендовали. Привожу примеры употребления: "Разрушение белков во всех типах клеток, кроме эритроцитов, осуществляется лизосомным и протеасомальным путями", "Протеасомальная деградация белка важна для протекания многих клеточных процессов". Другой вариант: "Защитный эффект протеасомных ингибиторов", "протеасомная деградация белков, участвующих в апоптозе необходима для выживания клеток". Все примеры я взял из литературы, которая у меня сейчас под рукой в бумажном варианте. Позже попробую привести ссылки на интернет-источники.

Answer (score 2):

**Суффиксы прилагательных Н и АЛЬН близки по значению**, они используются для образования относительных прилагательных с общим значением обладания признаком, качеством или свойством, названным мотивирующим словом.

**Во многих случаях выбор суффикса АЛЬН зависит от исходной основы** в том плане, что прилагательное должно быть удобным для произношения: артерия - артериальный, театр - театральный.

Но вопрос становится интересным, **если фонетически возможны обе формы, например: фигурный и фигуральный.** Фигурный - это связанный с фигурой определенной формы в прямом значении (фигурное печенье, фигурное катание), то есть Н - это суффикс самого общего значения. А вот фигуральный - это иносказательный, образный, переносный, связанный с риторическими фигурами речи. Таким образом, **суффикс АЛЬН передает оттенок частного значения.**

Если исходить из этих соображений, то **"протеасомный" - более предпочтительная форма**, в то время как протеасомальный может восприниматься как слово, имеющее дополнительное значение.

В текстах встречаются оба названия, так как фонетически они одинаково возможны. В то же время **желательно остановиться на одной форме**, которая используется в более авторитетных источниках.

Comment: *В текстах встречаются оба названия* - в каких?

Comment: Могу привести ссылки, в которых у одного и того же автора в статье использовано "протеасомальный", а в учебнике под его редакцией - "протеасомный". Для этих слов не существует разных значений, и на это не указывает контекст. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

"протеасомальный это:

Molecular biology: proteasomal (связанный с протеасомой - комплексом участка ДНК и защитного белка)

протеасомный это:

Molecular biology: proteasomal"

-- это из универсального русско-английского словаря.

"прилагательные: протеасомный" -- а это из викисловаря.

Вроде и то, и другое верно. Но точно не знаю.. пока.. я сам тут у вас учусь. ))

Comment: А в чем разница английских значений? Если она есть, то и при переводе обязательно сохранить. А если английские варианты синонимичны, то зачем сущности плодить?